# sending mail using php

Tags: php, smtp

I have seen similar questions here but , I am not beign able solve my problem .
I am trying to send mail using php... but this is not working .

```
<?php
$email_from="admin@crorebook.com";
ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
$headers = "From: $email_from";
mail('gitudrebel94@gmail.com','Registration confirmation','Hihihihihihih','$headers');
?>
```

It gives me the following error on a windows server :
"SMTP server response: 550  No such user here in"

And following error on a nginx server:

"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around `'$headers'`

Comment: you dont need the ini_set row

Comment: removed ini_set row , but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your outgoing mail server setup?  If you're running in windows you need an `SMTP` server, if linux you need `sendmail` or similar configured and running locally.

The SMTP error message suggests it's **NOT** an open forwarder - as in it won't just let anyone ask it to send an email to someone/somewhere else... that's good, because spammers would use it if it was.  It probably requires some kind of authentication (your username/password) before it will except email for delivery to anyone but those local to the machine (as in email addresses of domains hosted on the machine).

Unfortunately the PHP `mail()` method doesn't handle that so you need to look at a third party package - [PEAR mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail), or [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) are good options.

**To complete the task with PHPMailer:**

```
require_once /*lib location*/"phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
require_once /*lib location*/"phpmailer/class.smtp.php";

$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host=/*Your host*/;
$mail->Port=465;//For SSL - use this if you can
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";
$mail->SMTPDebug=2;//Comment once it works, but the debug info is invaluable
$mail->Username=/*Your username*/;
$mail->Password=/*Your password*/;
$mail->setFrom("admin@crorebook.com");
$mail->Subject='Registration confirmation';
$mail->Body='Hihihihihihih';
$mail->AddAddress('gitudrebel94@gmail.com');
$mail->Send();
```